# Finding nth degree polynomial functions

Tags: functions, polynomials

I need to find an nth degree polynomial function that has real coefficients using the following conditions:

n=3; 3 and 4i are zeros; f(2)=40

I have no idea what I'm doing on this one. It's been too long. Also, there's no homework tag because this isn't something I have to do. I'm just brushing up in preparation for an upcoming math course.

Comment: Hint : Since $3$ and $4i$ are zeros, you can factorize your polynomial like this : $f(z)=(z-3)(z-4i)g(z)$. What is the degree of $g$ then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want $3$ and $4i$ to be roots. If a real polynomial has a complex root, the conjugate also is a root. So we can just write down a polynomial that has exactly these roots:
\begin{align*}
f(x)=(x-3)(x-4i)(x+4i)=(x-3)(x^2+16)
\end{align*}
which indeed has only real coefficients and is of degree $3$. But the value at $2$ is not $40$ but $-20$ so the polynomial you are looking for is $g(x)=-2f(x)$.

Comment: I need to practice some more of these, but you've pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.